# Equivalent of sum product across multiple variables with prefixes

Tags: sql

I have a bunch of variables: `pretest1, pretest2, pretest3, ...`  Each of the pretestX variables are numbers.

I also have another bunch of variables in the same table: `posttest_1, posttest_2, posttest_3, ...` Also, all numbers.

For each record (aka row), I want to be able to generate the sum product of all of these:

```
sum (pretest_1*posttest_1, pretest_2*posttest_2, ...)
```

Is there a way to do this using column (aka variable) name prefixes? Can I do something like:

```
sum(pretest: * posttest:)
```

Or something like:

```
do i = 1 to 850
result = result + pretest_i * posttest_i
```

I am trying to avoid having to type all of the variables individually.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Just to be clear - you table have 2N columns - pretest1, pretest2 .. pretestN and posttest1, posttest2 ... posttestN, right?

Comment: there is no variables in database tables, they are columns, and you cannot do this with standard ANSI SQL, you need to use dynamic sql features which are DB dependend

Comment: @Mureinik - Correct. I am using proc SQL in SAS. I'm trying to do this in SQL instead of in a SAS data step.